# "There is no language C/C++"

Tags: discussion, tags, user-interface

Something that regularly demotivates me from participating on the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag is that when someone tags their question with both [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), certain community members immediately jump on the question with comments like "there is no such language, pick one". To me, their further conduct comes across as unhelpful or even abrasive.

This often happens when beginners in either language don't really know the difference between the two (let's face it, some programming languages just have *awful* names), but also when someone asks if something is possible in at least one of the languages ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271928/char-string-concatenation-without-copying)).

**Is tagging a question with both [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) almost always an error?**

1. If so, can we improve the interface to help users avoid this error? I'm thinking of warning the user before submitting the question when it has both of these tags. Such a feature could also be used to confirm that the user really meant [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell)+[pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipe), rather than [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell)+[haskell-pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-pipes).
2. If not, should the "There is no language C/C++"-type comments be forbidden? (AFAIK, "What have you tried?" is currently a forbidden comment on SO.)

Comment: People watch tags.  When someone adds your tag to a question that has nothing to do with the tag, it gets annoying after awhile.  You're wasting the few glances you spare such questions per day.  So, how about people use tags properly, and the problem goes away?  (Note, I'm not even a grumpy c++ dev, so imagine what their reaction is like!)

Comment: @Will I just consider that the price of experience. The large majority of questions on SO will be posed by beginners who make beginner's mistakes. If you want them to get on your level, you'll have to grant them some lenience. I might have different goals in mind for SO, but I'd rather have three mediocre but patient code monkeys answering my questions than a grumpy but skilled software architect.

Comment: Making a mistake has nothing to do with properly reading the fine and thoughtful guidance, we are not here to hand holding anyone, you are supposed to be a professional or enthusiast. Those people by the time they need help they have already checked out several books and read documentation.

Comment: If you don't know what language you're programming in, you 're not at the point where you should be asking questions here.  You're at the point where you buy a couple books and read them.  I say this as someone who recently bought a couple books on OOP in javascript, so it's good advice for this goose, not just for them ganders.

Comment: Those comments aren't in response to people using both tags, they're in response to people writing "C/C++" in their questions. See the revision history of that question.

Comment: Related: **[How can we stop SO suggesting both C and C++ tags on questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355331/how-can-we-stop-so-suggesting-both-c-and-c-tags-on-questions)**

Answer (score 3):

Both languages are similar, but there can be differences on how to approach or solve a particular problem.

This is why it's important to indicate *which* language you're using as opposed to tagging the question with both and hoping that someone will understand.

While the comments may be abrasive, I wish to give those who made them the benefit of the doubt in that they weren't trying to be abrasive; they were more trying to coax the asker into specifying which language they were meant to talk about.

The comments may not be all that useful in some respects, but at the same time, someone needs to ask, "Do you mean C or C++?"  Perhaps it should be asked a bit nicer.

Of course, there are *always* [valid questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547778/why-is-one-loop-so-much-slower-than-two-loops) that apply to [both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/1079354)...