# How can we stop SO suggesting both C and C++ tags on questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

One of the boring, recurring problems in the C and C++ ([c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)) tags is the questions that get tagged with both languages when only one is appropriate.  This is annoying to the cognoscenti who frequent the tags; it is one of the routine tasks to castigate people (mildly) for dual-tagging and then remove one of the tags — though it is sometimes difficult to tell which is the tag to remove.

However, it seems that part of the problem is that Stack Overflow *encourages* people to [use both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767213/reliably-accessing-pointer-accounting-data?noredirect=1#comment78492921_45767213):

> Just took the 3 suggested tags assuming the system knew better than I did.

No wonder we get so many dual-tagged questions!  (The third tag in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767213/reliably-accessing-pointer-accounting-data) was [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointers).)

- How can we stop SO from suggesting both the C and C++ tags?

---

I see the question [Disallow the tagging of questions with both C and C++ tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252430/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags) in the related (and/or linked) questions section on the right.  This is different.  I'm not seeking to prevent both tags; there are occasions when both tags are correct, usually when asking about how C and C++ interwork.  This question is asking that SO not encourage dual tagging — not that it prevent dual tagging.

---

#### Other tag pairs with a similar problem

Although the motivating pair of tags was C and C++, there are many other pairs of tags that should not normally be applied to a single question.  Extracting information from comments (and adding a spare):

- [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
- [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) and [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)
- [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl)
- [opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl) and [opengl-es](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl-es)
- [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) and [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)

- [ar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ar) versus [augmented-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/augmented-reality) and other tags related to augmented or virtual reality (not a high volume problem, but another persistent one)

---

As I noted in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355331/how-can-we-stop-so-suggesting-both-c-and-c-tags-on-questions#comment505962_355331) — lightly edited:

> Can the code which suggests tags be tweaked so that there's a table of 'improbable dual tags' such that if two of the tags are listed in it and both are selected, then a pop-up occurs saying something like "It is usually not correct to use both `[tag1]` and `[tag2]` on a single question — are you sure you should use both"? Entries in the table would be made manually when such pairs are identified — maybe the tag wiki section would allow suitably privileged people to nominate and vote for such pairs.

This is similar to, but arguably simpler than, the currently top-voted [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355346) by [user0042](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/8242698/user0042), with which I mostly agree.

[Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355331/how-can-we-stop-so-suggesting-both-c-and-c-tags-on-questions#comment506197_355346):

> Making this more general seems like a pretty good idea, actually. Only thing I would change is make it a moderator-only privilege, rather than a gold tag badge privilege. It doesn't need to be something that people fight over or change frequently (and there is already way too much fighting over [c] and [c++] tags).

I'm happy to have the 'suitably privileged people' be diamond moderators, but I wonder whether the suggestions would scale appropriately.  Would there be a MSO question raised for each proposed pair.  Is that desirable?
It probably depends on whether the number of pairs of tags is in the tens or if it moves into the hundreds or even thousands.  At larger scales, the wholly manual mode seems unlikely to be appropriate.  (As well as a mechanism to create 'inappropriate tag pairs', there'd need to be a mechanism to break such relations.  Again, questions on MSO can be used, and there should be less call for breaking such relations, especially if they have to be reviewed, approved, activated by diamond moderators.)

<sup>*I'm tempted to tag this as a feature request, or even as a bug!*</sup>

Comment: I seem to recall this coming up once or twice before.

Comment: I too would tag this as a *bug*.

Comment: When someone asks a question with something about pointers and dynamic memory, [tag:c] and [tag:c++] are both pretty good guesses for appropriate tags and it makes sense that they are both suggested. We could remove one of them if the other was picked. Or maybe we could do something like "if post contains `malloc` suggest [tag:c] otherwise suggest [tag:c++]". If you want this to actually get done you will have to make a very compelling case that it is worth it, because I'm not seeing SO putting this high on their todo list.

Comment: By the way, why is SO software not on github so you can send a pull request? I thought this is how such things are supposed to work nowadays.

Comment: What about those of us who prefer to write in C++ but have to put up with C libs, eg. to OS?  Such interop needs both tags.

Comment: @nwp about 50 % of the newbie questions to [tag:c] are also tagged [tag:c++], even though they're about **C**... 25 % of the [tag:c] newbie questions are then **C++** questions. Answering the question takes much longer when you need to ask the OP to ensure what the language being used actually is...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala if I see both tags, and there is no declared or obvious interop, then I downvote and move on.

Comment: See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769654/cant-traverse-from-tail-to-head-in-doubly-link-list#comment78497525_45769654) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769371/c-vector-error-char-unknown-size-vector-erase-iterator-outside-range#comment78497219_45769371) for latest examples.

Comment: @MartinJames so why do we suggest the newbies that they should tag them both? :D They initially wrote only *one* - presumably the correct one. Then the system says: "oh, why not add this too".

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I see why you want that and that it would be a good thing. But currently it's like "How about SO only shows me questions that I'm interested in and that I am most qualified to answer? Wouldn't that be cool?" Yes it would, but it's completely unrealistic. My suggestions are implementable, but I don't know if they would work on a significant number of problematic questions and how much work is required to get it done. The OP doesn't suggest anything.

Comment: @nwp this is why it is a discussion. The possible solutions should be posted as answers.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Then the system says: "oh, why not add this too" - agree, totally wrong:(

Comment: @nwp and notice that this absolutely **isn't** about how the questions are tagged, but about the posts that do not properly specify which language they're seeking the answer for - where the only hint is the tag, of which there are **2**.

Comment: @MartinJames I copied a C question without any C++ parts, or mentions thereto, and the suggested tags say: `C` `C++`. As a newbie afraid of doing anything wrong, that's what I'd do. It should do so that some of them are *exclusive* - after C is chosen, do not suggest C++ any more from the list. It could be *added* naturally. But I don't see why it should be suggested after C was chosen.

Comment: There are several other tag combinations that pop up quite frequently and (usually) do not make sense. I sometimes see questions taged with `Java` and `Javascript`. Other example is `OpenGL` and `OpenGL-es`. Or `Android` and `OpenGL`. I bet there are hundreds of other such examples.

Comment: Supposedly, the only way to manipulate what the system suggest is to modify the already tagged questions. So, if you want to have the system to suggest one tag, you need to edit all questions that are dual tagged.

Comment: @Braiam Or maybe tweak the algorithm to address the issue in this particular case.

Comment: Can the tag suggesting code be tweaked so that there's a table of 'improbable dual tags' such that if two of the tags are listed in it and both are selected, then a pop-up occurs saying something like "It is usually not correct to use both tag1 and tag2 on a single question — are you sure you should use both"?  Entries in the table would be made manually when such pairs are identified — maybe the tag wiki section would allow suitably privileged people to nominate and vote for such pairs.

Comment: Well, what tag would you offer as suggestion @Ron? If you ask a C question, suggesting C++ would be inappropriate, but the system can't also suggest C because it can't suggest both. Your best bet, is fix the questions that sports both tags or the wrong tag. There are at [least 32k examples of one of those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20c%2B%2B?mode=all), a non trivial proportion of each c and c++ tag separated.

Comment: It could be rather simple with the counter-indicated tags. Just render the suggested tags as `[c] or [c++]; [pointers], [undefined-behaviour]` User chooses one of the counter-indicated tags - remove the others from the view. They can still add them by hand. It is less of a trouble to *add* tags than to figure out whether the OP actually meant [c] or [c++].

Comment: Related (and very frequent and annoying): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304143/can-we-stop-suggesting-both-sql-server-and-mysql-in-the-suggested-tags

Comment: @BDL You can add AngularJS/Angular in the list :)

Comment: Having asked a question that I tagged (intentionally) as both `c` and `c++` I would like a solution to the needless bashing of those of us that use both.  I specifically asked for either a `c` or `c++` solution and got blasted.  Yes both languages are different but sometimes either can be used to solve a problem.  The 2 can be linked together rather easily.  If I asked for a solution using either `python` or `c` I probably wouldn't get the same vitriol.

Comment: @nwp The SE software is not open-source, if that's what you're wondering. I think they do have private repos on Github.

Comment: @Matt I came to read this here again. You should stop thinking Stack Overflow is here to solve **your** problem and your problem only. We're building a QA database here. If you really want to know **both** then you should ask 2 questions - and that would be totally OK. Then there are canonical answers for **both** distinct programming languages.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You just proved the point.  I argue for a use case of 2 different languages and you called me out.  It's not wrong to use both together.  The accepted answer provides a way to say this is not a mistake, I intend to tag and use two different languages in a solution,  no problem.  And SO exists to answer my question, your question and everyone's' question.  From help: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: @Matt I did call you out because of the exact problem that many people think that Stack Overflow should be just about solving their unique snowflake problem, now, right now. That's what the "too broad" means. If you're OK to use C++, then *most of the C* solutions would work for C++, so just tag the question with [tag:c++] and be done with it. The contrary is not true. A C++ template-metaprogramming solution / library doesn't help anyone having the problem in C.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala "unique snowflake" and "too broad" are completely contradictory.  And I'm done with this thread.

Comment: Also, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417367/how-about-the-addition-of-a-new-feature-which-checks-if-the-tags-on-a-post-make?noredirect=1#comment904416_417367

Answer (score 94, accepted):

> - How can we stop SO from suggesting both the C and C++ tags?

Since that's not a problem specific for the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tags (though a very prominent one), I'd like to propose the following feature:

- For every tag allow those with appropriate privileges (e.g. tag gold badge, or even official site moderators triggered by Meta Stack Overflow requests<sup>2</sup>) to keep a list of *"counter tags"*:

  > > ## About [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
  > >
  > > `C++ is a general-purpose programming language. It was originally designed as an extension to C, and keeps a similar syntax, but is now a completely different language. Use this tag for questions about code (to be) compiled with a C++ compiler.`
  > >     **Counter indicated tags:**
  > >     [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) <kbd>Edit</kbd>
  > >
  > > ...
- If the OP tries to add one of these counter tags after choosing the main tag and save their question, a warning should pop up

  > > **Warning!**
  > >     One or more of the tags you entered (*matching [counter-tag1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/counter-tag1), [counter-tag2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/counter-tag2), ...*) are likely not to be used in combination with [first-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/first-tag).
  > >     This could be an indication that your question might be
  > >
  > > - unclear
  > > - too broad
  > > - ... *maybe more reasonings*<sup>1</sup>
  > >
  > > Please read the related tag info-wikis to make sure this combination was intended by you.
  > >
  > > <kbd>I'm sure</kbd> <kbd>Cancel</kbd>

  May be even the <kbd>I'm sure</kbd> button shouldn't be enabled before the OP visited the relevant tag info wikis ([from here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355331/how-can-we-stop-so-suggesting-both-c-and-c-tags-on-questions/355346?noredirect=1#comment506481_355431)).
- That warning might disappear for users above a certain rep threshold (e.g same as the [established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)).

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>These could be kept as additional data for each particular *counter tag*.</sub>

<sup>2)</sup><sub>Picked up from [@Cody Gray's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355331/how-can-we-stop-so-suggesting-both-c-and-c-tags-on-questions/355346?noredirect=1#comment506197_355346)</sub>

Comment: This an interesting idea, although I believe that one should be conservative on what pairs are recorded, and limit the feature to cases where they are known to be problematic. As in, we should avoid the reasoning _"while we're at it, let's also add [tag:d] and [tag:c#], [tag:rust] and [tag:go], [tag:haskell] and [tag:swift], ... because we know that having these tags together is fishy."_

Comment: @E_net4 _"while we're at it, ..."_ If such feature once is realized I could think about extensions, e.g. such like general counter tag matching patterns kept by site moderators.

Comment: Certainly a good idea. `[access]` for`[ms-access]` is a good candidate too, the warning in the tag description doesn't seem to cut it sometimes

Comment: Seems like this might also make people less likely to ask code translation questions or the classic "I need to make a program, what language should I do it in?" stuff.

Comment: Another good candidate pair would be `[sql-server]` and `[mysql]`.

Comment: Making this more general seems like a pretty good idea, actually. Only thing I would change is make it a moderator-only privilege, rather than a gold tag badge privilege. It doesn't need to be something that people fight over or change frequently (and there is already way too much fighting over [c] and [c++] tags).

Comment: @user0042 I am not sure if a generic warning text will be effective in all cases. Sometimes it may be useful to point out the specific problem with a tag pair. If we go through with having it as a mod privilege, it might make sense to have a meta discussion regarding the warning content for every tag pair, before the changes are applied.

Comment: I think there are enough cases where a warning text is needed that this probably should go into tag wikis.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree that this should be a moderator tool. That being said, how would we suggest tag pairs such as C and C++ in this case? Should we create a post on Meta to draw attention to it?

Comment: Yes, via Meta, like everything else. It doesn't scale all that well, but it's what we have. @CoryKramer

Comment: Should be careful not to discourage questions around important differences - e.g. why things that look the same aren't behaving the same. This is likely to come up across `[c]`/`[c++]`, `[c++]`/`[c#]`/`[java]`, `[sql-server]`/`[mysql]`/`[postgresql]`, `[python-2]`/`[python-3]`, etc.

Comment: @OrangeDog I think that is one of the rare cases when people actually *should* tag both languages, e.g. "why does this code snippet produce different results when compiled in C vs C++" but those cases are far fewer than people mistakenly using both tags when they only are asking about one language or the other.

Comment: @CoryKramer that's my point - the warning should not give the impression that these questions are not allowed

Comment: Please, do that for `[angular]` / `[angularjs]` questions. It will save me a lot of time of editing.

Comment: @Mistalis We're already discussing a generic solution here. No need to add any other tag pairs that have the same problem over and over.

Comment: Except user Gimmethecodezplz doesn't read any of the text and just clicks "I'm sure". And then when someone brings up the issue with them, they start an edit war (yes this happens from time to time). I don't think warnings solve anything.

Comment: This would be somewhat hard to determine for `[actionscript-3]` and `[flash]`. One might fall off since one is simply a runtime and the other is the actual language it uses.

Comment: The problem with this is that sometimes there are 'conversion' questions where you want to work with data from two sources or converting one to the other, where both tags would be appropriate.

Comment: @TylerH Whenever the OP really thinks both tags apply, they can ignore that warning and click _"I'm sure"_.

Comment: @user0042 It wasn't clear from your post that the warning could be ignored/passed (except for 15k rep users, which is a pretty high threshold, IMHO)

Comment: @TylerH Well, my proposals rendering choice (3rd party cite) might not be the best, but I thought the `[I'm sure]` button in the warning pop-up clearly expresses that possibility.

Comment: @user0042 I see that now; I didn't look at the example mockups before, I just read the descriptions of how they would work.

Comment: @Tyler Also I thought _trusted user_ starts way below 15k, more something like 2000 or so (or even lower regarding the site bonus).

Comment: @user0042 Well, we were both a bit off - it's 20,000 reputation https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user

Comment: @Tyler Oh! I was coming from that site registration bonus, which is way lower (already achieved that). Misread _trusted_ probably ...

Answer (score 1):

For the specific issue of C versus C++, we have now tried to solve it by adding tag usage policies and user moderation guidance:

[Proposed update to C and C++ tag usage wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374306/proposed-update-to-c-and-c-tag-usage-wikis)

We did try a meta tag briefly [Possible meta-tag: [c++-cstyle]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372650/possible-meta-tag-c-cstyle), as proposed in my now deleted answer to this question. But after re-consideration, we went with the above linked approach instead.

The changes are now live to [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). This relies heavily on C and C++ gold badgers to enforce the policies. If it ends well, perhaps a similar system of user moderation can be used for other similarly problematic tags.

This doesn't however rule out the proposal by user0042. If such a feature would be implemented, there's now text from the tag wikis that could be used for displaying to the poster.

Answer (score -8):

You can not stop people from tagging things wrong. Simply because tags system required same learning as e.g. design. Some people do it better, some worse.

I don't think it's necessary to do something specifically for `C` and `C++`. The reasoning

> This is annoying

is simply not enough. I am mostly interested in `C#` and there are often people who use other language tags (`C`, `vb.net`, `java`, `java-script`, etc.), simply because:

- they know all of them and can use either;
- they have no clues;
- **OR** because maybe their question is regarding both (for e.g. pinvoke or marshaling).

Some cases with multiple tags are clear indicator of broad question, where doing anything with tags won't make it much less broad.

> though it is sometimes difficult to tell which is the tag to remove

Mark question as unclear, post comment or post an "i understand it this way"-answer.

I don't like idea of @user0042 with counter tags, it will only fix second case (where guy have no  clue). For any 10k+ rep user it takes just few clicks to change tags. Is this a real issue worth improvement? Nope.

Comment: Spamming multiple, completely unrelated language tags is probably a different problem. C and C++ are after all in many ways very similar languages. There are valid cases where both tags can be used.

Comment: Try hanging around in the SQL Server/MySQL tags, these two get combined incorrectly *all the time*, it's almost like [SO is trying to annoy us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304143/can-we-stop-suggesting-both-sql-server-and-mysql-in-the-suggested-tags) :)