# How to know the reason of deleted question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I have recently found [my question deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698476/is-1-correct-for-using-as-maximum-value-of-an-unsigned-integer). I don't feel anything bad about it but I just wanted to know the reason of it. I have created a chat room to talk to `Olaf` to know why he was the one and the first who wanted to delete this question. He told me mostly nothing interesting, just told his opinion:

**Olaf** says:

> There were 5 people deleting this, not me alone. And it was deleted because it would not roomba.
>
> On a sidenote: There is no language C++/C (or C/C++).

So, I wanted to talk about it but the next time he decided that he does not want to talk to me and told me that it is good to ask this question on meta instead of talking to him. So, maybe we should add "reason" field to let people know why their answer was deleted? Another question: why particularly this question has been deleted?

For people who want to say that this question should use only one tag (instead of both C and C++) I may say:

1. A lot of people use C constructions under C++ (yes, this is not really good but nevertheless).
2. It is still possible and not so difficult to answer this questions by explaining this problem in both, C and C++ languages. There are answers which corroborate that.
3. I did not even have a chance to correct tags so it would not be removed.
4. The question is duplicate, yes, but duplicates are not removed, and more, this question already had good answers before it was marked as duplicate.

P.S. I also can't find what is "Roomba". :)

For < 10k Users:

[image]

Comment: I think that you should separate the deletion issue from the "multiple language tags" issue.

Comment: @yivi I think Olaf told me that deletion and multiple language tags are related things..

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the answer for us sub-10K users? Related: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252430/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300162/tags-c-and-c-should-it-really-only-depend-on-the-posted-source)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth what screenshots exactly do you want?

Comment: One of the question, only the OP and users above 10K rep can view deleted questions

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I have added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Whoops, sorry, I added one too. My bad. Sorry if I overwrote yours :/

Comment: For your PS, view the [meta help centre on the Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)

Comment: And the [help page for roomba in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). Just googling "stack overflow roomba" gives you that as the first result...

Comment: @yivi Well, did not think to google it with "stack overflow" prefix somewhy. Thought this is some word which I just don't know, I am not an english native speaker.

Comment: Fair enough. Now you know. :)

Comment: Looks like your question ended up in the "Hot Network Questions" list.  It is a mixed blessing, you'll get the nay-sayers in proportion to the yay-sayers and it only needed 10 of them.  Well, 9 when Olaf is around.  Looks like it is heading for a re-open.

Comment: From my chat post (it was not a comment): "On a sidenote: There is no language C++/C (or C/C++)." That apparrently means the double-tagging issue was not the cause for deletion. I think I was very clear why **I** voted to delete: because it is a dupe and would not have roomba'd. In a follow-up post I recommended you learn how the site works. So what did you find about roomba, if none, what did youi try? (Hint: 1st google match for ["stack overflow roomba"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)). As I'm not the spokesman for the other Del-Voters, I can only speak for myself, of course.

Comment: If you ask why your question has been closed, read the close-reason. It is very clear (and correct).

Comment: "but duplicates are not removed" - Please provide a meta supporting your position.

Comment: @Olaf if you read what I wrote, you would not ask whether I checked what is roomba or not. You should have been more friendly talking about it and everything else. I would not ask this question here if you spent some time explaining what is this instead of "go read something anywhere else". The question was marked as duplicate but I have never seen duplicated questions deleted yet. This is why I asked why it was deleted.

Comment: _I also can't find what is "Roomba"_ Fine, that covers the first half. But apparently you did not really try. We are not a spoon-feeding community. You are expected to show some effort and google is certainly one of the basics skills. I am not required to explain why I did certain action, expecially as my own actions did have any effect without the actions of others. And offending someone in chat to make him explain is clearly not the way to get an explanation. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/161102

Comment: @Olaf I have already told because, again, it seems to me you did not read the comments above: I did no think it is only related to stackoverflow, I thought it is just a word I don't know. I googled it but with no success. Also, I don't understand this offense towards me. I have asked a question, a very easy question, why not just to tell me what I wanted to know? Don't have a time to help the community member?

Comment: One last thing: "I did not even have a chance to correct tags so it would not be removed." - The quesdtion was closed on 2017-12-08. It was deleted on 2017-12-13 (ca. 5 hours ago). You did not manage to edit it within those ~5 days?

Comment: @Olaf well, as I have already told, I thought it will just stay duplicated, but not deleted. Anyway, I don't care, just wanted to know why it was deleted instead of leaving alive but marked duplicated. Also, I have already got the answers before it was marked the duplicate, so I thought it is not necessary to do anything with it. Also, do you see? We could have talked about this in a chat room instead of talking here, in the comments section.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy duplicate questions deleted  often enough. The reason you don's see it happening is one generally can't see deleted questions... except the case it is your own question or question they favorited externally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As one of the delete voters:

I vote to delete because it was closed as a duplicate and is (in my opinion) a bad sign-post. It asks explicitly about a language standard and is tagged with two languages which could have completely different answers.

In addition, the question does not ask "What does the language standard say about X" but asks "Does the language standard say which is better" (it doesn't) and thus leads to a discussion about best-practice programming which is mostly opinion-based.

> A lot of people use C constructions under C++ (yes, this is not really good but nevertheless).

No, a lot of people use code which is similar between C and C++. Nevertheless, the same code can lead to different results in C or C++.

Read:

["There is no language C/C++"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312326/there-is-no-language-c-c)

[Disallow the tagging of questions with both C and C++ tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252430/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags)

[Question is tagged both [c] and [c++], but has no reason to be](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358560/question-is-tagged-both-c-and-c-but-has-no-reason-to-be)

> I did not even have a chance to correct tags so it would not be removed.

The discussion about which language standard should be applied started on December 8th. We deleted the question on December 13th. 5 days should be enough to correct a problem.

> The question is duplicate, yes, but duplicates are not removed, and more, this question already had good answers before it was marked as duplicate.

The question is not deleted if it is a good sign-post to find the original question (which it is not because of the multiple language issue).

Comment: I still see the question can have answers with both C and C++ standards. I understand why people say C and C++ are different languages but the quotation (which a few answers to original question corroborate) of both standards is tiny and people were able to write answers for both questions. However, I understand that it is difficult and people may not know both languages at a time so this question can cause answers with only one part (C or C++). I saw a comment by `chux` about choosing one only language but I did not think this will cause a deletion.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy You should be asking one question per question, not asking multiple separate questions per question.

Comment: @Servy probably you are right. But they would be almost the same question, just have different tags.. Would it be good?

Comment: I'd like to ask for a feature to show the deletion reason. Do you think it will be okay? Or it is unnecessary?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy In this particular case, neither individual question would be a good question as there are existing duplicates.  But if there weren't, and you actually needed to know the answer for this for two different languages, yes, you'd need to ask about it in two different questions, as the answers to those questions are completely different.

Comment: @Servy I think I agree with you. Just I program so many times switching from C to C++, so I thought there will be a very little difference in this particular question if any.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy They're different languages with different specs.  A question about what the specs for one of the languages say with respect to a given behavior can't be the same as the specs for an entirely different language.  When it comes to solving a programming problem in either language, if using features common to both, it's possible for there to be a common answer to both, but for a question about the specs, no answer referring to one language would ever answer a question asking about the other.

Comment: @Servy yes. And so I think my question is bad in this. Thanks.